# slideToggle acting weird on iPhone?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidetoggle

I am using the following code to have a drop down section (ul li's) after the user will click a button (img).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".buttonMenu").click(function (e) {
        jQuery(".slideDownMenu").slideToggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        jQuery(document).click(function() {
            jQuery(".slideDownMenu").hide();  
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideDownMenu">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a onClick="goToByScroll('home');">Home</a></li>
<li><a onClick="goToByScroll('gallery');">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a onClick="goToByScroll('team');">Team</a></li>
<li><a onClick="goToByScroll('contact');">Contact</a></li>
</ul><!-- menu -->
</div> <!-- slideDownMenu -->
<span class="buttonMenu"></span>
```

I am able to click on the button, have the hidden section displayed, click on a list item, be taken to the anchor link on the same page, the section will then hide after I click/tap a link but then, on iPhone, when I click again on the img/button, doesn't do nothing. I have to scroll the page from its position and then magic, the img/button is again clickable.

**Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?**

It only happens on iPhone/iPad. On Chrome, with iPhone as a user agent is fine. Also, there are no errors in the console.